# Proportionality rule

Tags: beamer, align, rules

I'm trying to write the proportionality rule  in `beamer`.

**MWE**

```
  \documentclass{beamer}
    \usetheme{Berlin} 
    \usecolortheme{beaver} 
    \usepackage[spanish]{babel}

    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

        \begin{document}

        \begin{frame}{Rule of 3}

        \begin{align*}
        & a unit 1 --- b unit 2\\
        & c unit 1 --- d unit 2
        \end{align*}

        \end{frame}
        \end{document}
```

**Question**

Is it possible write a small rule with controllable length instead of dashes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now there are two proposals:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Berlin} 
\usecolortheme{beaver} 
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Rule of 3}

\begin{align*}
& a~\text{\small unit 1} \,\rule[2.5pt]{16pt}{0.5pt}\,
b~\text{\small unit 2}\\
& c~\text{\small unit 1} \,\rule[2.5pt]{16pt}{0.5pt}\,
d~\text{\small unit 2}
\end{align*}

\begin{align*}
& a~\text{\small unit 1} -\!\!\!-\!\!\!- b~\text{\small unit 2}\\
& c~\text{\small unit 1} -\!\!\!-\!\!\!- d~\text{\small unit 2}
\end{align*}


\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Sorry, I first didn't catch the part on smaller. I hope to have done better now. **EDIT**: Incorporated @campa's suggestion.

Comment: @santimirandarp I agree. So you want the spacing of a minus but the length of an em-dash?

Comment: @santimirandarp Better now? I mean the first proposal, where you can fully control the length (just adjust the parameter `16pt`).

Comment: @santimirandarp You are the boss.;-) I have read the question differently, do you really want the horizontal line below the exressions?

Comment: `\rule` admits an optional parameter.

Comment: @campa Thanks! This would certainly be more elegant.

Comment: @santimirandarp You could write `\rule[2.2pt]{16pt}{0.5pt}` instead of `\raisebox{2.2pt}{\rule{16pt}{0.5pt}}`. Do you want me to update the answer accordingly?

Comment: @santimirandarp I tend to forget these things, and unfortunately the result of `latexdef \rule` is not too illuminating...